# How do you compress .manifest files the same way they are compress in "C:/Windows/WinSxS/Manifests"

Tags: windows, dll, compression, dism

I have a custom windows image that have certain files in "C:/Windows/WinSxS" edited.
The issue is that the files not longer match the hash stored in the .manifest file in "C:/Windows/WinSxS/Manifest" folder.
This causes issues when running DISM cleanup

I found: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/decompress-manifests-files-found-in-the-winsxs-folder.3367399/

Which explains how to decompress the .manifest file to allow me to edit them, but it does not cover how to re-compress those files so I can replace them.

How can I re-compress that manifest file?